# I am trying to build a repo and keep getting "libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_7.0.0' not found (required by /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6)"

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, libgcc

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with gcc 8 installed. I am trying to build a repo but keep getting the following error:

**libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_7.0.0' not found (required by /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6)**

I am new to Linux and not sure what might be the issue here. Thanks.

Comment: `lib32gcc-7-dev` https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lib32gcc-7-dev provides `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/32/libgcc_s.so.1`

Comment: I'm getting the same error using modelsim on Ubuntu 22.04 But can't find lib32gcc-7-dev to try to fix it yet.